# error #1005 - Can't create table (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `store` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`store_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `employee_phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `employee_mail` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `employee_username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `employee_password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `store_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `date_enter` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`employee_name`,`employee_username`),
 CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`store_name`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I am getting error

> error #1005 - Can't create table  (errno: 150)

Cannot spot error. Need help in resolving issue.

Comment: why not try to create the store table first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an index on your source table in order for the foreign key to work. For some reason MySql will create the index on the primary table for you if one doesn't exist, but doesn't automate this process onto the referenced table (source table).

Make an index for the store table and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary key on store is defined as `(id,store_name)` yet your are attempting to FK to it from `employee` based on one column only, viz

```
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`store_name`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_name`)
```

You would need to reference both columns of a primary key in a composite foreign key.

That said, it seems unnecessary to use composite keys here, given that AUTO_INCREMENT is already unique and a great candidate for a simple Surrogate primary key.

I would instead change the primary keys on both tables to just be the `AUTO_INCREMENT` id.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `store` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) -- *** Simple surrogate primary key
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `storeid` int(11) NOT NULL, -- FK to the surrogate PK, not the natural store name
  -- ... etc
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) -- *** Simple surrogate primary key
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`storeid`) REFERENCES `store` (`id`) 
         ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

*** Edit, Re, I want to use `store_name` as the foreign key**

In addition to a fk a primary key, you are also able to enforce referential integrity through a foreign key via a unique key constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `store` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE key `u_store`(`store_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- Other fields here
  `store_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `date_enter` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`store_name`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_name`) 
     ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: will you send me full query .

Comment: @user3576366 I've updated. I'm not quite sure you are understanding the problem here correctly - your original table structure has a composite primary key, which is redundant given that the AUTO_INCREMENT in itself is already unique. You can use store_name as a foreign key if you want (e.g. to save a join) but then you need to add a Unique Constraint on store_name in the store table. But I would still drop the composite keys. They are not necessary.

Comment: thanks a lot . Actually i didn't created an index. Actually  I am fresher for this sql . Once again Thanks